# Is $f(z) = z + \sin \left(\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{2020} z^n \right)$ analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am trying to see if the function $f(z) = z + \sin\left(\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{2020} z^n \right)$ is analytic. I tried using the geometric partial sum formula, but I am not sure if I can even use it since no precisions are brought to the value of $z$. Then, I get the derivative of $\sin \left(z \times \frac{1-z^{2020}}{1-z} \right)$, of which the real and imaginary parts are needed for verifying the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

If anyone has any pro-tips on steps to begin this problem it would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: $\sin(z)$ and any polynomial are analytic, so this is analytic by the chain rule.

Answer (score 3):

$\sin(z)$ and every polynomial  are [analytics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function), moreover the composition (and sum) of analytics functions is analytic, from here follows the thesis.

Answer (score 1):

$g(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{2020} z^n$ being a polynomial is an entire function and so is $h(z)=\sin z$; that is why their composition $h\circ g$ is entire. The sum of two entire functions i.e. $z+h\circ g$ must be entire too.